# Furtum est, secundum lege lata, contrectatio rei alienae fraudulenta

Tags: classical-latin, english-to-latin-translation, idiom, translation-check, grammar-choice

How to say this in proper, idiomatic, classical Latin?

> Theft is, according to existing law, laying hands on others' (foreign, strange, belonging to others) things fraudulently.

Would one use the genitive (*legis latae*) or the ablative (*lege lata*)?

I use *contrectatio fraudulenta* to translate laying hands fraudulently since I can't easily think of a noun to translate in English *contrectatio* which is a term in common legal use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Henry de Bracton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_de_Bracton), a medieval English jurist, in his book *De Legibus et Consuetudinibus Angliae*, [defined](http://amesfoundation.law.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/brac-hilite.cgi?Unframed%20Latin%202%20425) *furtum* as follows:

> … furtum est secundum leges contrectatio rei alienæ fraudulenta animo furandi, invito illo cuius res illa fuerit.
>   *… theft is, according to the laws, a deceitful touching of a thing that belongs to someone else with the intent to steal, against the will of him to whom the thing belongs.*

It seems unlikely that you were unaware of this rather famous definition or some derivative of it when you asked the question; if so, you might want to mention such things. Anyway, since you want *existing law*, as TKR wrote in his answer, you need *legem latam* and arrive at:

> Furtum est secundum legem latam contrectatio rei alienae fraudulenta.

The text is obviuously medieval (in fact, this very sentence really begins with: *Et sciendum quod furtum est …*). But the particular fragment you need, as far as I can tell, has nothing particularly unclassical in it.

Comment: I am actually Greek( Half-Greek Half-Brazilian) and I am not very fond of history. I simply see some Latin phrases in my Greek Law text books which don't seem right( Portuguese is a Romance language and some phrases strike me as foreign maybe because of word order or word choice). I didn't intend to plagiarise( not even the textbooks mention the medieval source that is why I was honestly unaware).

Comment: How could one communicate the need for the contrectatio to be commited with the intent to misappropriate( the intent to illegally dispossess someone of the thing and appropriate it themselves-add it to their property) so as to be considered theft?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Bracton does this with the addition of *cum animo furandi* – literally, “with the intent to steal.”

Comment: Cum animo furandi would mean With the intent of misappropriating? Why Genitve instead of Ablative( for the declination of furandus)? Am I risking circularity as TKR said because of the use the verb furor in a definition of the noun furtum or not?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Why the genetive? Because *animus* + gerund genetive means “the will/intention/desire/inclination of …” This is a rare example where [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Danimus) miss something important (unless I have overlooked it), but Georges [knows about it](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/animus?hl=animus). All his examples are from Justin and Velleius, so not medieval, but perhaps not Cicero & Caesar classical either.

Comment: I suppose the definition sounds a little circular on first hearing. Quid valet «furari»? Furtum facere. Quid est furtum? Contrectatio alienae rei. Omne contrectatio? Immo, nulla contrectatio nisi cum animo scilicet furandi! — I believe this is just intended to express that it is not theft if somebody does not think he is committing theft, e.g. because he believes he has a genuine right to take the thing. I am not a philosopher of law and feel somewhat underqualified to decide whether this is really circular.

Answer (score 6):

Neither genitive nor ablative: *secundum* takes the accusative, so the phrase would be *secundum legem latam*. You can usually find which case a preposition takes from its [dictionary entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsecundum).

Comment: Would **Furtum est, secundum legem latam, contrectatio rei alienae fraudulenta** be proper and idiomatic classical latin when translating **Theft is, according to existing law, laying hands on others' things fraudulently**?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos That looks grammatically correct to me. Of course Latin word order is flexible and context-dependent, so there would be various correct ways of phrasing this.

Comment: Could one add animo furando or cum animo furando to mean with misappropriating intent( with the intent to misappropriate)?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos That would not be a correct use of the gerundive -- *animo furando* would mean something like "by stealing a mind". (In any case it would risk circularity to use the verb *furor* in a definition of the noun *furtum*.)

Comment: How could one communicate the need for the contrectatio to be commited with the intent to misappropriate( the intent to illegally dispossess someone of the thing and appropriate it themselves-add it to their property) so as to be considered theft?